# babel for node.js version 6.9

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, babeljs

I don't know why in some project people use babel for node.js. I'm using node 6.9 I can write es6 without any problem, you name the feature, default argument in function, arrow function, rest and spread. Is babel really necessary in node?

The only thing I can't do is using import instead of required.

Answer (score 0):

Usually people use babel for node < 6.0 since those versions don't cover es6 that much.

Moreover node 6.9 doesn't cover es6 totally (ex : async/await functions, import syntaxe, ....)

Comment: `async`/`await` isn't in ES6.

Comment: No, not even that.

Comment: @mJehanno can we use import in node? I thought we have to use require as node is using commonjs?

Comment: @JennyMok You can't use import in node except if you use babel or any transpiler. Typescript support import syntaxe too since it just compile/transpile to es5/es6(choice is yours)